# "he minds contacting you" is this sentence correct

Tags: american-english

> he minds contacting you

Is there any mistake in the sentence? One of my friend told me that next word after mind need to be in its base form. I found that there have to be gerund form after like

Comment: "after like....", did you finish your question?

Answer (score 1):

Technically this is correct, but no native English speaker would say it, and on its own it is extremely ambiguous and awkward-sounding.

Assuming "minds" means "doesn't want to", then I suppose this sentence means "he doesn't want to contact you," which is much more natural-sounding.